# How to remove active_desktop_launcher.exe by KuGou

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, anti-virus

Hi I am running Windows Server 2012 R2. And I am facing a strange problem.

There active_desktop_launcher.exe service is randomly get executed and takes up 100% of CPU utilization slowing the whole server down. It automatically get executed even ending task from task manager

```
Detail:
active_desktop_launcher.exe 
Product Name: KuGou
Company Name: 酷狗音乐
https://threatinfo.net/files/active_desktop_launcher.exe-cd8dc9341aa5b888c3bd040e499c3cf2
```

[image]

I have installed MSE on server, but scan shows no result.
I am unable to install any other anti-malware software on the server.

Please advice how to remove this.
Thanks

Comment: You need to rebuild the system.

Comment: @Davidw rebuild means, update the windows available updates? Please explain a bit; if you know the solution. Will appreciate your help. Is "active_desktop_launcher.exe" from KuGou a malware?

Comment: Wipe and reload it. That is the appropriate process for dealing with malware on servers.

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell as administrator, then:
`cd C:\Users\Public\Documents\`
`TaskKill /IM active_desktop_launcher.exe /F`
`Remove-Item active_desktop_launcher.exe -Force`

Ultimately you need to wipe/reload the OS though, yes.

Answer (score -2):

You need to delete the file, then the windows will prevent you delete, coz you are running the process. Then go to task manager > performance > Resource Monitor > CPU

Then you will see the "active_desktop_launcher" running. Tick the process and right click, > End Process Tree. Immediately after that select the Files in the "Public Documents" folder process "Shift + Delete".

Then I sew a massive process was killed. I'm not sure what is going to happen after restart. So far so good.

Comment: Don't half-way remove it and then wait to see if it comes back. Wipe the server.